# How to install cordova?

Tags: cordova

I installed cordova like that :

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g cordova
```

And I get that a the end :

```
C:\Users\cyril\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\cyril\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\Users\cyril\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- cordova@6.4.0
```

And to test the install I run and get that :

```
C:\Windows\system32>cordova --version
C:\Users\cyril\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at WriteStream.stream.write (C:\Users\cyril\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\ansi\lib\newlines.js:36:21)
    at MuteStream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by uninstalling node 7.10.0 and reinstalling a previous version (6.10.3)